# RecyclerView only updates on app startup

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

newbie to Android here!

I've been learning how to implement SQLite in my app, and to sum it up, I have an `Accountant` class which has access to the SQLite database. The class pulls up the items from the database and puts them in an `ArrayList`. This `ArrayList`  is what is used for my adapter for the recyclerView.

Whenever I add a new item in the app, the the item's data is stored in the database and the `Accountant` class's `ArrayList`gets updated with this info.

Then, the adapter calls its `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to update the View. This is where the problem occurs; the `RecyclerView` DOES display all items, but only upon app startup, NOT when a new item is added.

I've done all I can, it just LOOKS like it's supposed to work, but it doesn't and it's driving me nuts.

Here's the code

**ItemAdapter Class**

```
private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {
        private List<Item> mItemList;

        public ItemAdapter(List<Item> itemList) {
            mItemList = itemList;
        }

        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int ViewType) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemHolder(view);
        }

        public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
            Item item = mItemList.get(position);
            holder.bindItem(item);
        }

        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItemList.size();
        }
    }
```

**Accountant Class**

```
public class Accountant {

    private static Accountant sAccountant;

    private double mTotalMoney;
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private List<Item> mItemList;

    public static Accountant get(Context context) {
        sAccountant = sAccountant == null ? new Accountant(context) : sAccountant;
        return sAccountant;
    }

    private Accountant(Context context) {
        mTotalMoney = 0;
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mDatabase = new ItemBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
        mItemList = getListFromSQL();
    }

    private static ContentValues getContentValues(Item i) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ItemTable.cols.NAME, i.getName());
        values.put(ItemTable.cols.PRICE, i.getPrice());
        values.put(ItemTable.cols.COUNT, i.getCount());

        return values;
    }
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        ContentValues cv = getContentValues(item);
        mDatabase.insert(ItemTable.NAME, null, cv);
        mItemList = getListFromSQL();
    }

    public void removeItem(int i) {

    }

    public void addMoney(double money, boolean isSet) {
        mTotalMoney += isSet ? money - mTotalMoney : money;
    }

    public String getTotalMoney() {
        return MoneyUtils.prep(mTotalMoney);
    }

    public String getChange() {
        double cost = 0;

        for (Item item : getItemList())
            cost += item.getPrice() * item.getCount();

        return MoneyUtils.prep(mTotalMoney - cost);
    }

    public List<Item> getItemList() {
        return mItemList;
    }

     private List<Item> getListFromSQL() {
         List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

         ItemCursorWrapper cursor = queryItems(null, null);
         try {
             cursor.moveToFirst();
             while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                 itemList.add(cursor.getItem());
                 cursor.moveToNext();
             }
         } finally {
             cursor.close();
         }
         return itemList;
     }

    public ItemCursorWrapper queryItems(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(ItemTable.NAME, null, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);

        return new ItemCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }

    public String individualPriceOf(Item i) {
        return MoneyUtils.prep(i.getPrice());
    }

    public String totalPriceOf(Item i) {
       return MoneyUtils.prep(i.getCount() * i.getPrice());
    }

    public String countOf(Item i) {
       return String.valueOf(i.getCount());
    }

    public void clearList() {
        mDatabase.delete(ItemTable.NAME, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Item adding logic**

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    mAccountant.addItem(item);
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mAccountant.getListFromSQL().size() - 1);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChangeButton.setText(mAccountant.getChange());
}
```

Comment: if your data model is `Cursor` based use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter, its like a `CursorAdapter` for "normal" `ListView`s

Comment: @pskink So it'll also work for RecyclerViews?

Comment: `public abstract class CursorRecyclerAdapter<VH
  extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the app still only updates on startup. Should I change the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method?

Comment: read [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-android-cursorloader-example), notice point **2,** of `There are three key benefits of using a CursorLoader`

Comment: you can also read the official [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) guide

Answer (score 0):

Well there is fundamental problem not even related to `RecyclerView`.
First let's see how to fix your issue then explanation of what's wrong.

change this

```
private List<Item> mItemList;
```

to this

```
private final List<Item> mItemList;
```

then instead of any assignment like `mItemList = getListFromSQL();` write this

```
mItemList.clear();
mItemList.addAll(getListFromSQL());
```

Now explanation why your code is not working. The thing is that when you assign your dataSource (i.e. `mItemList`) to some new value you are changing reference to it (that's a java fundamental thing) so that your RecyclerView doesn't know anything about it and it's own dataSource which you assign only once in constructor remains the same old one which is not changed therefore your `notifyDataSetChanged` call does nothing.

General advice whenever using `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` make sure you define your dataSource as `final`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you do not add the item into your Adpater's list. Make a method inside your adapter and call this method from your Accountant class.

```
private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {


     public void addItem(Item item) {
         mItemList.add(item); ///Add the item to your arrayList and then notify
         notifyItemInserted(mItemList.size());

}
```

When you add single item in Adapter dont call    notifyDataSetChanged() method because it will notify the whole list. Instead only use notifyItemInserted() method.
Another think is make sure when you notify the adapter it must be from UI thread.

When you add your item then just call this adapter addItem() method from your Accountant class.

```
public void addItem(Item item) {  ///This method is from Accountant Class
    mAccountant.addItem(item);
    mAdapter.addItem(item); // Call the addItem() from Adapter class
    mChangeButton.setText(mAccountant.getChange());
```

}

Hope it will work...